# Need Help Synchronizing a Global Interval for All Users in React (TS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, synchronization

My React TS application is designed to flip through a list of images on 10s intervals, but now ***I'm trying to synchronize the interval for all users*** so that they see their images change the exact same time, no matter their connection and/or location. Is there a way to do this? If so, how can I go about doing it?

My first attempt was `unsuccessful` after trying to utilize the Javascript `Date milliseconds` and modulating it by 10000, taking the remainder and offsetting the initial state interval, but it proves to be unreliable ([code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-forest-ue1zd4?file=/src/ImageSyncDateMilliDiff.tsx)).

I've also tried the `useTime hook` from `react-time-sync` which worked until my users were on separate devices ([code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-moon-5lpivf?file=/src/ImageSync.tsx)). This approach seems to be most promising so here's the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTime } from "react-time-sync";

const slideUrls = [
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/250/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/300/300"
];

const ImageSync = () => {
  const syncInterval = useTime({ unit: 10 }); // 10 seconds
  const [slideUrl, setSlideUrl] = useState<string>("");
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlideIndex((slideIndex) => slideIndex + 1);
  }, [syncInterval]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlideUrl(slideUrls[slideIndex % slideUrls.length]);
  }, [slideIndex]);

  return (
    <>
      <img src={slideUrl} alt="img" />
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageSync;
```